# Windows Phone 8 : dllimport does not work

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to import a coredll and use one of its apis in C# Windows Phone project
This is the code snippet

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 GetLastError();
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           GetLastError();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
      }
```

I get the following exception on Windows Phone 8 handset
        System.NotSupportedException: DllImport cannot be used on user-defined methods
**P.S: this is true for any API not just this API.**
The coredll is a C++ library and I am using it in C# project.
What is going wrong here ?
Thanks,
Viral

Answer (score 2):

What's going wrong is that `DllImport` is not supported on Windows Phone 8. You'll have to use Windows Runtime components (either existing or ones you write yourself) to bridge between C++ and .NET languages.